# Contracts not running in Web3 after upgrading to solidity 0.5

Tags: web3js, solidity-0.5.x

I have a cotract that used to work with web3 and solidity 0.4.21 now I'haven't been able to get a god answer from web3 although my tests work perfectly. this is my contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./MyContract.sol";

contract ContractsManager {

    address public owner;
    MyContract[] public contracts;

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getContracts() public view returns (MyContract[] memory) {
        return contratos;
    }
}
```

This is my js:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    this.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
}
else {
    this.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
}
web3 = new Web3(this.web3Provider);

var ContractsManagerArtifact = await $.getJSON('ContractsManager.json');
var MyContractArtifact = await $.getJSON('MyContract.json');

this.solContracts.ContractsManager = TruffleContract(ContractsManagerArtifact);
this.solContracts.MyContract = TruffleContract(MyContractArtifact);

this.solContracts.ContractsManager.setProvider(this.web3Provider);
this.solContracts.MyContract.setProvider(this.web3Provider);

this.manager = await this.solContracts.ContractsManager.deployed();
var addresses = await this.manager.getContracts();

for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    var contratoSol = await this.solContracts.MyContract.at(address);
}
```

When I test my getContracts() function using `truffle test`, it returns an empty array `[]` but in my javascript the getContracts() function its returning `undefined`.

I tried changing my web3.js version with the same result, am I missing something for solidity 5.0 to work well with web3.js?

Thanks

Comment: It's solidity 0.5, not 5.0.

Comment: And you need to explain what exactly you have upgraded, since there are 3 components here - Solc, Web3 and Truffle. If you've upgraded Truffle from v4.x to v5.x, then you've implicitly upgraded Solc from v0.4.x to v0.5.x and web3 from v0.x to v1.x.

Comment: I completely installed the application in a new computer installing Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7), Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js) and Node v10.15.2. I tried also updating web3.js and truffle-contract.js using the latest CDNs but TruffleContract stoped working so I left my old files that sadly were pasted in the project and I don't know their versions.

Comment: Comparing it to some CDN I think I have web3.js version 0.19.0

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I had to update my web3 code too, started using webpack and migrate using `truffle migrate --reset` to add my contracts again to ganache after a restart I made.

This is my js:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const contract = require("truffle-contract");
this.web3Provider = Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://localhost:8545';
this.web3 = new Web3(this.web3Provider);

var ContractsManagerArtifact = await $.getJSON('ContractsManager.json');
var MyContractArtifact = await $.getJSON('MyContract.json');

this.solContracts.ContractsManager = contract(ContractsManagerArtifact);
this.solContracts.MyContract = contract(MyContractArtifact);

this.solContracts.ContractsManager.setProvider(this.web3Provider);
this.solContracts.MyContract.setProvider(this.web3Provider);

this.manager = await this.solContracts.ContractsManager.deployed();
var addresses = await this.manager.getContracts();

for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    var contratoSol = await this.solContracts.MyContract.at(address);
}
```